# Who approved the document?

Tags: approval, workflow-history

I have an approvals workflow set up with an email which is activated automatically when the document is pending review/approval.  Each document has a different approver; the approver's name is inserted in a field and the field is referred to as part of the workflow.  How do I get to see the name of the person who actually approved the document? This is really to test that the workflow is doing it's job and that there is no-one else interfering!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your workflow histories and you will see where the names against each task or each workflow are listed.